# Stop reading inputstream after specified number of bytes

Tags: java, inputstream

Is there a way to divide an input stream into chunks? For instance, I am sending an input stream to a BodyPublisher, and I would like that BodyPublisher to read a subset of the input stream and stop, then, the next iteration would read the next set of bytes in the input stream.

I guess another way to ask this is, is there an input stream that can wrap another input stream and return end of stream after a specified number of bytes?

It might look something like:

```
InputStream is = // my inputstream
while (bytesRead < numBytes) {
   SubsetInputStream subsetIs = new SubsetInputStream(is, chunkSize);
   ...
   .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofInputStream(() -> subsetIs));
   ...
   bytesRead += chunkSize;
}
```

Comment: Is it an option to read the bytes in a `byte[]` array and put it in a `ByteArrayInputStream`, which will be used for your BodyPublisher?

Comment: I was hoping to avoid the extra memory of reading the data into a byte array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems trivial to make it yourself:

```
import java.io.*;

public class LimitedInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
  private int limit;

  public LimitedInputStream(InputStream in, int limit) {
    super(in);
    if (in == null) throw new NullPointerException("in");
    if (limit < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("limit must be positive");
    this.limit = limit;
  }

  @Override public int read() throws IOException {
    if (limit < 1) return -1;
    limit--;
    return in.read();
  }

  @Override public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
    if (limit < 1) return -1;
    int lim = Math.min(len, limit);
    int r = in.read(b, off, lim);
    if (r > 0) limit -= r;
    return r;
  }

  @Override public void close() throws IOException {
    in.close();
  }

  @Override public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
    long lim = Math.min(n, limit);
    long r = in.skip(lim);
    if (r > 0) limit -= r;
    return r;
  }

  @Override public int available() throws IOException {
    return Math.min(in.available(), limit);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    var raw = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[256]);
    var lim = new LimitedInputStream(raw, 100);
    byte[] b = new byte[55];
    System.out.println(lim.read(b)); // prints 55
    lim.read();
    lim.read();
    System.out.println(lim.read(b)); // prints 43
    System.out.println(lim.read(b)); // prints -1
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks pretty good. Why did you extend FilterInputStream?

Comment: FilterInputStream conceptually is 'a stream that does not itself represent a resource, instead, it wraps around one and modifies how it works'. And that's exactly what this is, so, appropriate. Implementation-wise it buys us virtually nothing, though. Actually, that `close()` method I wrote? I think you can just delete ethat, that's what FilterInputStream already does by default.

Answer (score 3):

There is [BoundedInputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/BoundedInputStream.html) in [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) that does exactly what you need:

```java
InputStream is = // my inputstream
while (bytesRead < numBytes) {
   BoundedInputStream subsetIs = new BoundedInputStream(is, chunkSize);
   ...
   .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofInputStream(() -> subsetIs));
   ...
   bytesRead += chunkSize;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could read into a byte array and create a `ByteArrayInputStream` from that.

```
var chunk = new byte[chunkSize];
for (int read; (read = is.read(chunk)) != -1;) {
    var bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(chunk, 0, read);
    // use the ByteArrayInputStream
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid the extra memory of reading the chunks into a byte array.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... Is there a way to divide an input stream into chunks? ..."*

Yes, although it's not part of the syntax.
You'll have to create a new *[ByteArrayInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html)* object for every segment.

The *Java* framework typically functions around *mutable* and *immutable* states, so dividing an object is not a common feature.
Although, some classes do provide this functionality—e.g., the *[ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)* class.

Nevertheless, you can utilize the pseudo-code you provided.

I believe the simplest approach here is to use the *[InputStream#read](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D,int,int))* method.

The *bytesRead* here is not accumulative, and is per iteration.

```java
try (InputStream is = // my inputstream) {
    int bytesRead, chunkSize = 100;
    byte[] b = new byte[chunkSize];
    InputStream subsetIs;
    while ((bytesRead = is.read(b)) != -1) {
        subsetIs = new ByteArrayInputStream(b, 0, bytesRead);
        .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofInputStream(() -> subsetIs));
    }
}
```

> *"... I guess another way to ask this is, is there an input stream that can wrap another input stream and return end of stream after a specified number of bytes? ..."*

You could encapsulate an *[InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html)*, and *override* a *read* method, delegating the data from there.
I recommend this if you plan on scaling the code.

Otherwise, the *read* method will return *−1* once the end of the stream is reached.
Here is the *JavaDoc* excerpt.

> ***Returns**:*
> *the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or -1 if there is no more data because the end of the stream has been reached.*

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using extra memory required to read the bytes into byte arrays. What you describe about encapsulating InputStream seems like the direction I'll take; it is the solution @rzwitserloot proposes.

Comment: @broadbear, you'll still need a new object each time.  There is an _[ofByteArray](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.html#ofByteArray(byte%5B%5D,int,int))_ method.  I suggest switching to that unless the _InputStream_ is required.